# Testing Mongoose Models using AVA

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, exception, ava

I've been trying to test mongoose models using [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava).

As validation errors tend not to be type errors I tried various things and came to this working way:

The Model

```js
// Model

// Require Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * Story Point Report Schema
 * The timestamps used in this way create updatedAt and createdAt automatically
 */
const storyPointsSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { 
        required: true, 
        type: String, 
        maxLength: 100
    },
    lastName: {
        required: true, 
        type: String, 
        maxLength: 100
    },
    team: {
        required: true, 
        type: String}
    ,
    storyPoints: {
        type: Number
    },
    sprint: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        startDate: {
            required: true,
            type: Date, 
        },
        endDate: {
            required: true,
            type: Date,
        }
    }
  
}, {timestamps: true });

storyPointsSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    this.spintStartDate = Date.now();
    this.sprintEndDate = Date.now() + 14;
})

/**
 * Calculate Full Name
 * Virtual for ticket assignee's full name
 */
storyPointsSchema.virtual('name').get(() => {
    let fullname = ""
    if (this.firstName && this.lastName) {
        fullname = `${this.firstName}, ${this.lastName}`
    }
    return fullname
})

function convertDateToReadableFormat(Date) {
    return  DateTime.formJSDate(Date).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_MED);
}

storyPointsSchema.virtual('prety_dates').get(() => {
   return {
        sprintStartDateF: convertDateToReadableFormat(this.spintStartDate),
        sprintEndDateF: convertDateToReadableFormat(this.spintEndDate),
        updatedAtF:  convertDateToReadableFormat(this.updatedAt)
    }
})

export const StoryPoints =  mongoose.model('StoryPoints', storyPointsSchema)
```

The AVA unit test that currently passes

```js
import test from 'ava';
import {StoryPoints} from '../../models/story_points.js';
let storyPointsSchema = null;

test.before(t => {
    storyPointsSchema = new StoryPoints();
    storyPointsSchema.sprint.endDate = Date.now();
    storyPointsSchema.sprint.startDate = Date.now();
    storyPointsSchema.sprint.name = "Story Points Test";
    storyPointsSchema.team = "The Testers";
    storyPointsSchema.firstName = "Joe";
    storyPointsSchema.lastName = "Smoe";
});

test("Undefined first name should have error 'Path `firstName` is required.'", async t => {
    const sPs = new StoryPoints();
    const except = async () => {
       throw new Error(await sPs.save());
    }
    try {
        await except();
    } catch(e) {
        t.deepEqual(
            'Path `firstName` is required.',
            e.errors.firstName.properties.message
        )
    }
});
```

I hope this helps someone!

If you have a better way to do this then please share; otherwise have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I did try t.throwsAsync() however it wasn’t catching the Mongoose validation errors which is how I came to this solution.